# What is the equivalent action inside Power Automate which mimic creating tasks inside Workflow designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, power-automate, flow, approval-process

I have this workflow designer 2013 >> which create a task and wait for response:

[image]

So I am planning to redesign this using Power Automate, so inside power automate what is the equivalent action to create workflow task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **Approvals** in Power automate flows which can be used in place of Tasks in SharePoint designer workflows.

**Documentations**:

1. [Create and test an approval workflow with Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals)
2. [Get started with approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/get-started-approvals)
3. [Trigger approvals from lists created with Microsoft Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-sharepoint-list)